# Custom posts template page

Tags: custom-post-types, templates

## I want to create a custom template for my job post listing

I have registered a new custom post type, `job`. Then I have created a template for a single job post, `single-job.php`, which works fine.

But when I enter URL `www.xyz/job` all records are displayed using the `index.php` template which, is the one that my blog uses. How can I create custom template for `www.xyz/job` records so I can edit it independently without touching blog template, which is `index.php`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A specific post type template could be created with `archive-{post_type}.php` -> `archive-job.php`.

Here is a good descriptive image of the template hierarchy in WordPress. [image]
Read more about the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/)